# How to hide Gridpanel GroupCommand in Ext.Net

Tags: ext.net

I am working with Ext.Net1.0. and I am working with Grid Panel with grouping
In that I had set Group Command I want to hide Group Command..

[image]

```
<ext:ImageCommandColumn Width="110">
                    <GroupCommands>
                        <ext:GroupImageCommand CommandName="Delete" Icon="Delete" Text="Delete" RightAlign="true">
                            <ToolTip Text="Delete" />
                        </ext:GroupImageCommand>
                        <ext:GroupImageCommand CommandName="Edit" Icon="TableEdit" Text="Edit" RightAlign="true">
                            <ToolTip Text="Edit" />
                        </ext:GroupImageCommand>
                    </GroupCommands>
                </ext:ImageCommandColumn>
```

How can I get GroupCommand??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done with  in ext:ImageCommandColumn and In prepareGroupCommand Function we can get Command Name through(command.command).

Answer (score 0):

You can look in this thread http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?11425-CLOSED-Reach-Command-coloumn-at-run-time-with-javascript&p=46416&viewfull=1#post46416

Comment: this link didnot help to me.. reason is that I am working with group command and another is i had added **<Listeners>
<Command Fn="commandHandler" /> </Listeners>**  commandHandler was not called at all

Comment: Done with **<PrepareGroupCommand Fn="prepareGroupCommand" />** in ext:ImageCommandColumn and In prepareGroupCommand Function we can get Command Name through(command.command).